# Rails scope method for "included in many-to-many"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The scope method below is in my `Deal` class. A deal `has_many` `origins` (which are `Airports`. So `Deal.from_airport(dca)` will return all deals from DCA.

```rb
scope :from_airport, -> (airport) {select {|d| d.origins.include? airport }}
```

This method works fine, but returns an array. Is there a way to implement this so that it returns an ActiveRecord relation?

---

Re-Update: Thanks to @NeverBe, I now have the first two "plural" filters set up (I used his/her answer for the first to figure out to construct the second):

```rb
  scope :from_airports, -> (airports) { 
    joins(:origins).where(airports: {id: airports.map(&:id)}) 
  } 

  scope :to_regions, -> (regions) { 
    joins(:region).where(regions: {id: regions.map(&:id)}) 
  }
```

However, I'm still having trouble with `for_vacations`.

Since

1. it's not dealing with relations (like `Deal has_many :airports; belongs_to :region`) but rather with properties (`start_date` and `end_date`) and
2. it's dealing with comparison rather than equality,

the techniques above, using SQL such as `WHERE "airports"."id" IN (2502, 2686, 2816)` don't work.

Below is the "old" code as well as my best shot at a method that would return a `Relation`.

```rb
  # "Old" code: Returns the right objects, but as an array rather than as an ActiveRecord relation
  scope :for_vacations, -> (vacations) do
    select do |deal|
      vacations.any? do |v| 
        v.deals.include? deal 
      end
    end
  end

  # "New" code: Throws error, see below.
  scope :for_vacations, -> (vacations) { 
    where.not('start_date >= ?', vacations.map(&:end_date))
    .where.not('end_date <= ?', vacations.map(&:start_date))
  }
```

The new code gives this error:

```rb
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of NOT must be type boolean, not type record
       LINE 1: SELECT "deals".* FROM "deals" WHERE NOT (start_date >= '2020...
                                                       ^
       : SELECT "deals".* FROM "deals" WHERE NOT (start_date >= '2020-12-31','2020-10-31','2020-03-31') AND NOT (end_date <= '2019-12-01','2019-10-01','2019-03-01')
     # ./spec/models/deal_scopes__filters_spec.rb:110:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # PG::DatatypeMismatch:
     #   ERROR:  argument of NOT must be type boolean, not type record
     #   LINE 1: SELECT "deals".* FROM "deals" WHERE NOT (start_date >= '2020...
```

Any heroes to the rescue?

Comment: use `where` instead of `select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
scope :from_airport, -> (airport) {joins(:origins).where(airports: {id: airport.id}) }
```

Comment: for airports relation: scope :from_airports, -> (airports) {joins(:origins).where(airports: {id: airport.ids}) }

Comment: Thanks but the code as you gave it doesn't use the `airports` argument. I tried changing the `where` argument to `{id: airports.ids}` and even `{ids: airports.ids}` and each threw `undefined method `ids' for #<Array:0x00007ff39aacd4e8>`. Thoughts?

Comment: but airports must be a relation! not an array ! or change airports.ids -> airports.map(&:id)

Comment: Thanks, `scope :from_airports, -> (airports) {joins(:origins).where(airports: {id: airports.map(&:id)}) }` appears to do the trick. Hopefully I can extrapolate this into the `to_regions` and `for_vacations` plural filters as well.